# Reset/format corrupt HDD with write protected partition

Tags: external-hard-drive, filesystem-corruption, write-protect

I screwed up the partition map on a removable HDD, corrupting it, and would like to reset it.

The problem is that one of the partitions is write protected, and common solutions that merely do not work.

The partitions are:

- disk2s2 : 0kb
- disk2s4: 999.99 GB
- disk2s3: -1 MB (that's right, it's negative!)

It's using a GUID partition map

This happened on macOS, but I have access to any os really... When viewing the FS on Ubuntu it says the gpt partition table is corrupt, and of course any efforts to reset it is foiled by I would assume write protection, but any commands to remove write protection don't seem to work (e.g. `sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sda` doesn't work and yields no error messages)

Comment: Why don't you backup what you want to save, wipe the HDD, and start over with a fresh partition table?  You can probably spend more time waiting & looking for a *possible* solution than simply performing a straight-forward do-over.

Comment: I would love to do that, but Disk Utility won't let me erase the drive (possibly because of write protection)

Comment: `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/XXX count=63` should zero out the first "track" of the HDD.  Just be careful that you properly specify the HDD you want to wipe.

Comment: running this command w `/dev/sda` seems successful, I get `63+0 records in
63+0 records out
32256 bytes (32 kB, 32 KiB) copied, 0.000213441 s, 151 MB/s`. But nothing seems to change, when I run gparted I get `The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.`, and when attempting to auto-fix I get `Input/output error during write on /dev/sda`, and drive doesn't seem to be wiped

Comment: There's a backup partition table at the end of the drive.  You'll need to get the total number of sectors of the drive, and subtract 63 from this number. then run the other command again, and also `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/XXX seek=ZZZ`, where ZZZ is that calculated number of sectors.  *"attempting to auto-fix ..."* -- ***Why not start over, and create a brand-new partition table???***

Comment: I found the sector size of the disk by using `fdisk -l`, then ran `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda seek=1953525167`, I got: `dd: writing to '/dev/sda': No space left on device
1+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 0.000128593 s, 0.0 kB/s`. But the disk seems to be unaffected. I did double verify and the disk is indeed called `sda`

Comment: *"But the disk seems to be unaffected"* -- Of course, because the command reported `0 bytes copied`.  You didn't follow the directions because you did not subtract any offset from the total number of sectors.